# Remove inner texts and input elements from HTML through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I remove all input elements and inner texts from my html using Javascript?

this is my html:

```
<div>
  <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">
    <b>Tick Below</b>
  </span>
  <p>
    <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">
      Movie : <input type="checkbox" value="movie"><br/>
      Books : <input type="checkbox" value="movie"><br/>
      Browsing : <input type="checkbox" value="movie"><br/>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Output Should be:

```
<div> 
  <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">
    <b></b>
  </span>
  <p>
    <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically you want to clear out everything inside the span tags?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using ES6 *template literal*:

```
var element = document.body; // if it's not the entire body :
// var element = document.querySelector('div.className');
var new_html = `<div> 
<span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">
<b>
</b>
</span>
<p>
<span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
</span>
</p>
</div>`;
element.innerHTML = new_html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably remove all input elements using below script with jQuery.

`$(function() {
    $('input').each(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
});`

Below code will serve your desired outcome.

`$(function() {
    $('span').each(function() {
       $(this).contents().filter(function(){
            return !$(this).is('br');
        }).remove();
    });
});`

Comment: OP doesn't say he have access to JQuery ;)

Comment: jQuery is for lazy programmers

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('span input').forEach(function(inp) {
    inp.remove();
});
document.querySelectorAll('span *,span').forEach(function(el) {
    [].forEach.call(el.childNodes, function(child) {
        if (child.nodeName == '#text') {
            child.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

> for IE11, and maybe as far back as IE9 - this code is more universally compatible

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('span input'), function(inp) {
    inp.parentNode.removeChild(inp);
});
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('span *,span'), function(el) {
    [].forEach.call(el.childNodes, function(child) {
        if (child.nodeName == '#text') {
            child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution doesn't seems to be working fine in IE 11.

Comment: that's because internet explorer doesn't support the element.remove method - a polyfill is available - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill - to clarify, what error do you get in IE11 for this code?

Comment: I see another issue with IE11 - let me fix that up

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working no JQuery needed:

```
function removeTxt() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");          
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].parentElement && elements[i].tagName=="INPUT"){
            elements[i].parentElement.removeChild(elements[i]);
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        for (j=0;elements[i].childNodes && j<elements[i].childNodes.length;j++){
            child = elements[i].childNodes[j];
            if(child && child.nodeType == 3) {
               elements[i].removeChild(child);
               i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution doesn't seems to be working in Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: @ShrinathShetty tested on IE11 seems to be OK.

Comment: Input controls are removed but not the inner text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be putting all of those in one span tag, if you don't want to cheat using CSS to get custom check boxes, then you should just work like this:

```
<div>
    <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">Movie: </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="movie"><br/>
    <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">Books: </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="movie"><br/>
    <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:8px">Browsing: </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="movie"><br/>
</div>
```

I also don't recommend putting that CSS inline. Use an internal or external style sheet. You can really easily look this up on the internet... I'll show you how simple it could be using an internal style sheet.

```
<head>
<style>
span {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:8px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <span>Movie: </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="movie"><br/>
    <span>Books: </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="books"><br/>
    <span>Browsing: </span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="browsing"><br/>
</div>
</body>
```

Now, for the JavaScript part, you could get all the elements with the matching tag by using the querySelectorAll function and then delete those. So if you adapted your HTML to the more semantic version I gave you, this should do the trick:

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
Array.prototype.forEach.call( input, function( node ) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
});

var input = document.querySelectorAll("span");
Array.prototype.forEach.call( input, function( node ) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
});
```

Or you could also just put a div tag around every span + input, give that div a class and in javascript do a querySelectorAll(".checkbox-container") and remove those.